# Why $h^\sharp - k^\sharp$ factors through $\mathcal{I} = \ker(i^\sharp)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $i : Y \longrightarrow T$ be a closed immersion of ideal $\mathcal{I}$.
Let $h, k : T \longrightarrow X$ be two morphisms of schemes such that
$$ h \circ i = k \circ i. $$
I try to prove that $h^\sharp - k^\sharp$ factors through $\mathcal{I}$.

We have
$$ 0 = h_*(i^\sharp) \circ h^\sharp - k_*(i^\sharp) \circ k^\sharp $$
and for an open $V$ in $X$ and $s \in \mathcal{O}_X(V)$,
$$ 0 = i^\sharp_{h^{-1}V}(h^\sharp_V(s)) - i^\sharp_{k^{-1}V}(k^\sharp_V(s)). $$
I don't see how to use that.

Comment: What do you mean by "factors through $\mathcal I$"? $\mathcal I$ is a sheaf on $T$, not on $X$.

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as $h^\sharp - k^\sharp$. You cannot subtract sections of different sheaves.

Comment: @danneks You are right. I try to understand the construction of the exterior differential. Here $i = \Delta : X \rightarrow X \times_S X$ is the diagonal immersion and $d_{X/S} = p_2^\sharp - p_1^\sharp$ where $p_i^\sharp : \mathcal{O}_{X \times_S X} \rightarrow (p_i)_*\mathcal{O}_X$ and $p_1 \circ \Delta = p_2 \circ \Delta = id$.

Comment: Could you give a source for this construction?

Comment: @danneks see https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bruno.klingler/cours/Weil.pdf (page 35), https://math.berkeley.edu/~ogus/Math_256B-2017/Notes/differentialsandsmoothness.pdf (proof of Theorem 6) or Bosch's book (page 356).

Comment: At the first link ${p_i}^\sharp$ are maps of sheaves on the same topological space ($X$) and $p_i$ is identity on the level of topological spaces. In this case the problem reduces to a problem about maps of modules, which is obvious.

Comment: @danneks Thanks for your help.